# If the selection is changed in the select2, it records the two values

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 in a form in which I select a client, but if I return and change the selection once or more times to the database, all the concatenated names arrive.

In the HTML, I have the select2:

```
<select class="custom-select form-control-sm" id="inv_cntId" name="inv_cntId"  required></select>
```

The script is like this:

```
$("#inv_cntId").select2({
    placeholder: 'Seleccione un Cliente',
    allowClear: true,
    SingleSelection: true,
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
    url: 'core/ContactSearch.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 50, //milisegundos
    processResults: function (data) {
        return {
        results: $.map(data, function (obj) {
            return {
            id: obj.id,
            text: obj.text,
            address: obj.address
            };
        })
        };
    },
    cache: true
    }
});
```

How can I solve this behavior?

Comment: I probably is due to the `ContactSearch.php` code.

Comment: `$result [] = ['id'=>$row['cnt_id'], 'text'=>$row['cnt_co'], "code"=>$row['cnt_code'], "address"=>$row['cnt_address'].", ".$row['cnt_city']];`

the field is text